# NullPointerException after a try to access database via Hibernate

Tags: java, spring

I try to develop a simple web application, but to exclude all the possibilities of a mistake in the web front-end, I have written a little class which I execute from a command prompt.

```
package org.vadim.testmvc;

import org.vadim.testmvc.model.*;
import org.vadim.testmvc.service.*;
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Strings s = new Strings();
        TestService ts = new TestService();
        s.setText("StrText");
        ts.addStrings(s);
        System.out.println(ts.listStrings());
    }
}
```

TestService.java (without import statements but be sure they are present in the original listing):

```
package org.vadim.testmvc.service;

@Service
public class TestService implements TestServiceInterface {

    //@Autowired
    TestDAO testdao = new TestDAO();

    @Transactional
    public List<Strings> listStrings(){
        return testdao.listStrings();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addStrings(Strings strings){
        testdao.addStrings(strings);
    }
}
```

TestDAO.java:

```
package org.vadim.testmvc.dao;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class TestDAO implements TestDAOInterface {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addStrings(Strings strings){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(strings);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Strings> listStrings(){
         return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Strings").list();
    }
}
```

Entity class:

```
package org.vadim.testmvc.model;

@Entity
@Table(name="STRINGS")
public class Strings {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="TEXT")
    private String text;

    public void setId(Integer id){
        this.id=id;
    }

    public Integer getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getText(){
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        this.text=text;
    }   
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<mapping class="org.vadim.testmvc.model.Strings"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

root-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.vadim.testmvc.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.vadim.testmvc.service"/>
<import resource="data.xml"/>
</beans>
```

data.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation">
    <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
    <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

This is the stack trace after the exception encounters:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.vadim.testmvc.dao.TestDAO.listStrings(TestDAO.java:23)
    at org.vadim.testmvc.service.TestService.listStrings(TestService.java:18)
    at org.vadim.testmvc.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:11)
```

The same happens if I try to execute TestDAO.addStrings(Strings strings) method, that is to say that the problem is not in the return result of listStrings(), but in the access to the database. I have tried either to add some entries from mysql command prompt, to make it not empty. I succeed to do that but that didn't influence the behaviour of the programm.

Here is what I get if just declare `TestService testservice;` with @Autowire annotation

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.vadim.testmvc.dao.TestDAO org.vadim.testmvc.service.TestService.testdao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.vadim.testmvc.dao.TestDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.vadim.testmvc.dao.TestDAO org.vadim.testmvc.service.TestService.testdao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.vadim.testmvc.dao.TestDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.vadim.testmvc.dao.TestDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: make sure everything is freshly deployed. The exception means that the dao is not recognized as spring bean, but it should, because it is annotated with @Repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find it is a combination of @Bozho and @smp7d answers. You need to load the spring configuration, make sure you have defined a bean for the TestDao in that configuration  AND uncomment the @Autowired.

Comment: Maybe it is a kind of a dumb question but what do you mean under loading of spring configuration? Should I add to the root-context.xml something like `<bean id="testdao" class="org.vadim.testmvc.dao.TestDAO"/>` ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have commented out `@Autowired`, but it causes your problem:

```
//@Autowired
TestDAO testdao = new TestDAO();
```

When you create `TestDAO` manually Spring is not able to inject `TestDAO.sessionFactory`, which is left `null`. Uncomment this annotation and remove `= new TestDAO()`:

```
@Autowired
private TestDAO testdao;
```

Comment: I just have edited my post to show the result of that. I tried to do that initially and than I changed to the view I presented.

Answer (score 0):

In your main method, you are not loading the spring configuration...so the class members will not be autowired.

Load your configuration, get your TestService bean from the context/bean factory, and make sure you autowire TestDao.

Answer (score 0):

please try to add this in dao;

public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
    public Session session = null;

```
@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}
```

Comment: it's not the problem that he doesn't use the template

Comment: yes you are right overlooked you can try 
sessionFactory.openSession() instead of sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

Answer (score 0):

ı thing it doesnot get current session
you can use sessionFactory.openSession() instead of sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()